# Excel Floor function

Tags: excel, function

I am confused regarding excel floor function. Mathematically, floor (x) is the largest integer not greater than x. Following this definition, I expected, 
Floor( -3,-2) to display -4 , but it displays -2.
Can somebody explain why?

Comment: According to [office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/floor-function-HP010342531.aspx), the FLOOR function rounds down to the nearest multiple of the significance value.  In this case, you gave -3 as the input and -2 as the significance, and -2 is the nearest multiple of -2 when rounding down.  At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: @Tim - rounding down normally means rounding toward negative infinity, so the result should definitely be (-4). What excel is doing is plain wrong.

Comment: ... but to update my comment (and be fair...) in Excel 2010 (at least) the behavior seems to be correct when the significance is positive. So, `floor(-2.5,1) = -3` and is doing the expected thing.

Comment: It is a very confusing function with no adequate explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

`FLOOR` function - Rounds a number down, toward zero

`FLOOR.PRECISE` function - Rounds a number down to the nearest integer or to the nearest multiple of significance. Regardless of the sign of the number, the number is rounded down.

```
=FLOOR(-3,-2) is -2
=FLOOR.PRECISE(-3,2) is -4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using negative significance revert behavior.

From documentation:

> If number is positive and significance is negative, FLOOR returns the #NUM! error value.
>
> If the sign of number is positive, a value is rounded down and adjusted toward zero.
>
> If the sign of number is negative, a value is rounded down and adjusted away from zero. If
> number is an exact multiple of significance, no rounding occurs.

However, testing positive and negative number and significance I get following result:

- Significance > 0:

  - Any number: Round down (toward negative infinity)
- Significance < 0:

  - Number < 0: Round up (toward positive infinity)
  - Number >= 0: `#NUM!`
- Significance = 0:

  - Number = 0: `0`
  - Number <> 0: `#DIV!`

Comment: Assuming this is correct, it is a great explanation of this strange function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Number - the value to be rounded.

Significance - the function rounds the Number specified above down to the nearest multiple of this value.

Floor(-3,-2)

As here **-3** is the number and **-2** is the significance So if we see multiple of -2 than 0(-2*1),-2(-2*1),-4(-2*2),-6(-2*3) but here NUMBER -3 is round down to the nearest multiple of -2 is itself **-2**(Answer).

Try this Floor(-3,-4) gives 0.

Comment: As your definition says, "the function rounds the Number specified above DOWN to the nearest multiple of this value," since it rounds down, should the answer not be -4 for Floor(-3,-2)

Comment: to the nearest multiple of significance.So it is giving -2